# How to get current language with ngx-translate in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I want to get current language with `this.translate.getBrowserLang()`, but it always return 'en', whatever the current language is and what the supported languages is.

Here is the plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/JEXgj8WcISYGtDg75VoR?p=preview,

---

maybe plnkr has broken, you can try stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kk1mud-a7gxbb

Answer (score 84):

import translate service and add in constructor

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService){
}
```

I find it use `this.translate.currentLang` to get the current language

Comment: how to access this translate.currentLang ?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry just use `this.translateService.currentLang`, dont forget to add the `TranslateService` in construtor

Comment: Is there a way to get an observable of the current language?

Comment: @MatejaPetrović en.. I think current language is not a observable like property, but you can subscribe the onLangChange of translate service.

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.translate.currentLang;
}
```

Comment: not sure why it's giving me `undefined`

Comment: @RickyLevi you need to set the language first using this.translate.use() and using the string of the language as a parameter ('es', 'en', etc.). If you have not set the language, or it it's overwritten or lost during the app's lifecycle, currentLang will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a valid language, even though you never set one, make sure to set the default language when you import the ngx-translate module

**app.module.ts**

```
...
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
         defaultLanguage: 'en'
      })
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```